# Getting System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object . Trying to update Account Description field as OpportunityLineItem Desc

Tags: trigger

```java
trigger OppLineItem on OpportunityLineItem (after insert) {
    
    if(trigger.isAfter && trigger.isInsert)
    {
        Set<Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>();
        Set<Id> AccIds = new Set<Id>();
          
        List<Account> AccToUp = new List<Account>();
        
        for(OpportunityLineItem oppI :trigger.new)
        {
            oppIds.add(oppI.OpportunityId);
        }
        
        List<Opportunity> oppList = [select id, AccountId from Opportunity where Id in :oppIds];
        
        if(! oppList.isEmpty())
        {
            for(Opportunity op:oppList)
            {
                AccIds.add(op.AccountId);
            }
         
        }
        
        
        
        List<Account> AccToIt = [select id, Name, description from Account where id in :AccIds];
        Map<Id, Account> AccIdMap = new Map<Id, Account>();
        
        if(!AccToIt.isEmpty())
        {
            for(Account acc :AccToIt)
            {
                AccIdMap.put(acc.Id, acc);
            }
        }
        
       
              
             
        for(OpportunityLineItem oppI :trigger.new)
        {
            if(!AccIdmap.isEmpty()) 
            {
                 Account acc = AccIdmap.get(oppI.Opportunity.AccountId); 
                 acc.Description = oppI.Description;
                
                 AccToUp.add(acc);
            }
           
        }
             
       
        if(!AccToUp.isEmpty())
        {
            update AccToUp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: oppI.Opportunity.AccountId seems problem to me also Map<Id,Account> AccIdMap = new Map<Id,Account>([select id,Name,description from Account where id in: AccIds]);. you can hold oppId & description as map and then populate to account

Comment: what will you do if an account has two opportunities in the transaction? they will have different descriptions - which one wins?

Comment: @cropredy... Latest inserted OpportunityLineItem Description should get updated ...It is not according to business logic but for practice and better understanding

Comment: derek's final 5 bullets are the solution

Answer (score 3):

The issue is `Account acc = AccIdmap.get(oppI.Opportunity.AccountId);`.
As written, your `acc` variable is guaranteed to be null.

If you go back to your error and look at your stack trace you should be able to confirm that you're being pointed to the line just after this one. I.e. `acc.Description = oppI.Description;`

`null.<anything>` gives you a Null Pointer Exception. `acc` is null. So you in effect have `null.Description = oppI.Description;`

`oppI` is being pulled from `trigger.new`, and trigger context variables *never* contain related data. If you need to use more than one dot/period/full-stop to access data, then you need to explicitly query for that data.

You're basically already doing that query (i.e. the query that you put into `oppList` contains the data you need).

While there are a number of improvements that you could stand to make to your code (getting rid of nearly all of those extra blank lines, better variable naming, using a single query instead of two, etc...), the bare minimum that you need here is:

- put the result of your Opportunity query into a map instead of a list
- in your final loop, use the OLI's OpportunityId to get the Opp from the map (mentioned above)

  - then use the Opp to get the relevant Account from `AccIdMap` using the Opp's `AccountId` field

Setting aside the utility of setting the Account Description to the Description of an OLI (a single Account can have multiple Opps, and each Opp can have multiple OLIs. Which description should be used?), a better approach would be:

- Gather OLI Ids
- Query OLIs, and use dot-notation to query for the AccountId of the parent Opportunity
- Iterate over the queried OLIs, and use the SObject constructor to create a new Account and set the Id and Description
- Put the new account into a map
- Perform a DML update on the map's values (e.g. `update myMap.values();`)